# python pandas error: too many indices for array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe of columns that I would like to convert to numeric, like so:

```
for col in df.columns[22:33]:
   df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors = 'coerce')
```

Which works great.  However whenever I try to include more than a single range, like so:

```
for col in df.columns[22:66, 68, 69, 71, 72, 74:79, 81:86, 88, 89,91:94 ]:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors = 'coerce')
```

I get the error,

```
IndexError:  too many indices for array
```

Is there a way around this, I would like to not have to do it over and over for each range.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the functionality of `np.r_`. You pass in array of numbers and slices, it will construct/concatenate them into the expanded array.

```
cols = np.r_[22:66, 68, 69, 71, 72, 74:79, 81:86, 88, 89,91:94]

array([22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38,
       39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55,
       56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 68, 69, 71, 72, 74, 75, 76,
       77, 78, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93])
```

After that, you may use `cols` as

```
df.columns[cols]
```

Comment: this is perfect!  Simple and exactly what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: @jvalenti: glad I could help

Comment: Notice that the behavior is slightly different, e.g. `22:66` results in columns 22-65 whereas it would be columns 22-66 using `df.loc[:, 22:66]`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create 2 loops then. Create a list with elements consist of the ranges, then loop on it, inside this loop insert your original for loop code.

Like:

```
for i in range_list:
    for col in df.columns[i]:
        #do your code here.
```

Your `range_list` will have the ranges you need.

Comment: in theory this works.  the problem I had with it was that I couldn't find a way to specify my ranges that was syntaxtically consistent.  I tried lists and tuples and it didn't work.

Comment: I see the problem with that but I still think its doable. Basically the ranges you must be tuples of intergers to store int values say `range_list = [(22,66)...]` and so on then during the second iteration  call each value by `df.columns[tuple first element : tuple second element]` explicitly.

Comment: Or maybe you are referring to the single range input like `68,69,71`? If that's the case just create a range for them. So the code will hold.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your target columns represent integers names for the columns in the dataframe (per your example), you can munge the string and concatenate the result.

```
target_cols_str = "22:66, 68, 69, 71, 72, 74:79, 81:86, 88, 89, 91:94"
df_series = []
for col in target_cols_str.split(','):
    col = col.strip()  # Remove any whitespace.
    if ':' in col:
        lhs, rhs = col.split(':')
        df_series.append(df.loc[:, int(lhs):int(rhs)])
    else:
        df_series.append(df.loc[:, int(col)])
df2 = pd.concat(df_series, axis=1)
```

Applied to your example to convert the original dataframe to numeric values:

```
target_cols_str = "22:66, 68, 69, 71, 72, 74:79, 81:86, 88, 89, 91:94"
for col in target_cols_str.split(','):
    col = col.strip()  # Remove any whitespace.
    if ':' in col:
    lhs, rhs = col.split(':')
    for col_name in range(int(lhs), int(rhs) + 1):
        df.loc[:, col_name] = pd.to_numeric(df.loc[:, col_name], errors = 'coerce')
    else:
        df.loc[:, int(col)] = pd.to_numeric(df.loc[:, int(col)], errors = 'coerce')
```

Comment: I don't quite understand.  The integers are the column indexes.  Will this allow me to convert the columns as well?  Thanks.

Comment: If the numbers represent integer locations of the columns, just convert all `loc` values above to `iloc`.  I just demonstrated conversion of the columns per the second example.

Comment: When I run this I get the error: TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

Comment: @AndyL. Modified the solution to account for that.